# Using inner classes for multiple implementation inheritance

Tags: java

I'm reading a book "Thinking in Java" that states the following about inner classes:

> Each inner class can independently inherit from an implementation. So one way to look at the inner class is as the rest of the solution of the multiple-inheritance problem. Interfaces solve part of the problem, but inner classes effectively allow "multiple **implementation** inheritance". That is, inner classes effectively allow you to inherit from more than one non-interface.

I've never used inner classes like that. So I started to thinking about how this could look and where this can be useful. I came up with this:

```
public class ReadWriteCollection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var rw = new ReadWriteCollection();
        var ro =  rw.new ReadPart();
        var ao =  rw.new AddPart();

        ao.add("foo");
        System.out.println(ro.read(0));
    }

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    class AddPart extends AddOnlyCollection {
        void add(String s) { list.add(s); }
    }

    class ReadPart extends ReadOnlyCollection {
        String read(int index) { return list.get(index); }
    }

    public abstract static class ReadOnlyCollection {
        final void someExistingImplementation(){  System.out.println("Foo"); }
        abstract String read(int index);

    }

    public abstract static class AddOnlyCollection {
        final void someExistingImplementation(){  System.out.println("Bar"); }
        abstract void add(String s);
    }
}
```

`ReadOnlyCollection` and `AddOnlyCollection` represent some existing implementations that I can't control. I've put them inside `ReadWriteCollection` just for convenience in my example.

So is it how inner classes should be used for "multiple implementation inheritance"? Can somebody give more examples and possible usages for this technique? Or is it the way inner classes were used in the past and no longer used like this (the book is quite old)?

Comment: With default methods being available for interfaces and sealed classes now allowing for more fine grained access control I don't think you'd need that approach that often.

Comment: I'm also not sure I call this "inheritance" since the inner classes do not have a "is-a" relation to the outer class. It's basically just more of a composition type of relation, i.e. the inner classes are "part-of" the outer class and have access to the outer class' methods and fields much like a "normal" relation would allow you to do (with differences in access control).

Comment: @Thomas yeah. Here, outer class is acting like a facade. Like in facade pattern.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks! Indeed, this seems to be more an implementation of the composition with the benefit of nested objects having access to private members of the class. Can you maybe elaborate more on how default methods in interfaces and sealed classes make this patter obsolete?

Comment: Well, default methods would allow you to have multiple inheritance of behavior and sealed classes would allow you to restrict implementations to known types so `ReadWriteCollection` could implement `ReadOnlyCollection` etc. and if necessary those interfaces could also allow `ReadWriteCollection` as their only implementation. It doesn't make the pattern completely obsolete but probably less necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the idea of the author is the following to by-pass the multi inheritance restriction in Java:

```
public class A {}
public class B {}
public class C {}


public class MainTest {

private AA aa;
private BB bb;
private CC cc;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AA aa = new AA();
    BB bb = new BB();
    CC cc = new CC();
 }

private static class AA extends A {
    
 }

private static class BB extends B {
    
 }

private static class CC extends C {
    
 }
}
```

With that you have extended three different classes inside your `MainTest`.

Comment: What would be the difference to declaring those classes outside `MainTest`, potentially in the same file? In your case the `static` keyword basically makes `MainTest` act like a namespace anyway and even without `static` I could always add a `MainTest` reference to any of those classes to access the methods and fields of that instance. The only real advantage I'd see in that case would be that (static) inner classes have access to private members of the outer class - so it's more of an access control mechanism than actually multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Thomas It's just an example, there is no real usage of it. I suspect that it is what the book author had in mind..

Comment: Yeah, I know this is just an example and your take on what the author had in mind. I'm basically just disagreeing in calling this multiple inheritance, especially if the author had this in mind. :)